# jQuery auto-complete texbox with asp.net gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, autocomplete

I have an auto-complete jQuery textbox and an asp.net gridview data-bound to some db data.

The user selects some item from the auto-complete textbox and in response I create an ajax call to the server to get data relevant for that selection and try to bind the relevant data to the gridview.

The problem is that, the gridview does not change its data, and remains with the old datasource although I changed it - the gridview gets new datasource on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you can add some of your code so we can figure out what/where the problem is?

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel?

Comment: You could try to add a templatecolumn on gridview and add a textbox there, apply a css style on this textbox and get it by jquery and apply the autocomplete. Post your code to be get more detail to us :)